# Error with getline

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, getline

I'm getting an error here, and am not sure why, I'm very new to c++ and if you could look at the rest of my code, to make sure it is alright that would be great.

I'm getting an error on these two lines.

```
getline(in, e.first, ',');
getline(in, e.last, ',');
```

It's saying class Employee has no member First, and I know that it's not in that function, how can I fix it?

Here is the rest of my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Person {
    string first;
    string last;
};

struct Address {
    string street;
    string city;
    string state;
    string zipcode;
};

struct Employee {
    Person name;
    Address homeAddress;
    int eid;
};

void readEmployee(istream& in, Employee& e);
void displayEmployee(ostream& out, const Employee& e);

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    Employee e[50];

    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;

    fin.open("employeesIn.txt");

    if (!fin.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening employeesIn.txt for reading." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    fout.open("employeesOut.txt");
    if (!fout.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening employeesOut.txt for writing." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    int EmployeePopulation = 0;
    readEmployee(fin, e[EmployeePopulation]);
    while (!fin.eof()) {
        EmployeePopulation++;
        readEmployee(fin, e[EmployeePopulation]);
    }
    fin.close();
    for (int i = 0; i <= EmployeePopulation - 1; i++) {
        displayEmployee(fout, e[i]);
    }

    fout.close();

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

void readEmployee(istream& in, Employee& e) {
    string cidText;
    if (getline(in, cidText, ',')) {
        e.eid = stoi(cidText);

        getline(in, e.first, ',');
        getline(in, e.last, ',');

        getline(in, e.homeAddress.street, ',');
        getline(in, e.homeAddress.city, ',');
        getline(in, e.homeAddress.state, ',');

        string zipcodeText;
        getline(in, zipcodeText, ',');
        e.homeAddress.zipcode = stoi(zipcodeText);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Employee` doesn't have a member `first`. `Person` does but not `Employee`.

Comment: How would you recommend fixing it with what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You need to do the same you do with `Address` you accessed through `homeAddress` member variable. In the case of Person, you need to add `.name` member variable (ex: `getline(in, e.name.first, ',');`

Comment: I don't understand how you could have written the next three lines correctly, and still not know what to do with those two incorrect lines. It's the exact same thing, just with a different member. Did you even write this code?

Comment: Ah thank you very much, I forgot about the whole nesting deal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about we rename the **Person** struct to be a **Name** struct instead?
(It only contains a **first** and **last** after all.)
That would give us this:

```
struct Name {
    string first;
    string last;
};
```

So what does an Employee look like now?
It looks like this:

> ```
> +-------------+
> |  Employee   |
> |             |
> | +---------+ |
> | |  Name   | |
> | +---------+ |
> |             |
> | +---------+ |
> | | Address | |
> | +---------+ |
> |             |
> +-------------+
> ```

**Name** is a part of **Employee**, but where is **first** and **last**?  They are a part of **Name**.
Here is the same picture, except it goes a layer deeper to show you **first** and **last**:

```
+---------------+
|   Employee    |
|               |
| +-----------+ |
| |   Name    | |
| |           | |
| | +-------+ | |
| | | first | | |
| | +-------+ | |
| |           | |
| | +-------+ | |
| | | last  | | |
| | +-------+ | |
| |           | |
| +-----------+ |
|               |
|  +---------+  |
|  | Address |  |
|  +---------+  |
|               |
+---------------+
```

You need to use TWO dot operators ('.'), to access **first** and **last**, because they are TWICE as deep.

```
Employee e;
e.name.first = "Joe";
```

Your code as been re-factored to reflect these changes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Name {
    string first;
    string last;
};

struct Address {
    string street;
    string city;
    string state;
    string zipcode;
};

struct Employee {
    Name name;
    Address homeAddress;
    int eid;
};

void readEmployee(istream& in, Employee& e);
void displayEmployee(ostream& out, const Employee& e);

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    Employee e[50];

    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;

    fin.open("employeesIn.txt");

    if (!fin.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening employeesIn.txt for reading." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    fout.open("employeesOut.txt");
    if (!fout.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening employeesOut.txt for writing." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    int EmployeePopulation = 0;
    readEmployee(fin, e[EmployeePopulation]);
    while (!fin.eof()) {
        EmployeePopulation++;
        readEmployee(fin, e[EmployeePopulation]);
    }
    fin.close();
    for (int i = 0; i <= EmployeePopulation - 1; i++) {
        displayEmployee(fout, e[i]);
    }

    fout.close();

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

void readEmployee(istream& in, Employee& e) {
    string cidText;
    if (getline(in, cidText, ',')) {
        e.eid = stoi(cidText);

        getline(in, e.name.first, ',');
        getline(in, e.name.last, ',');

        getline(in, e.homeAddress.street, ',');
        getline(in, e.homeAddress.city, ',');
        getline(in, e.homeAddress.state, ',');

        string zipcodeText;
        getline(in, zipcodeText, ',');
        e.homeAddress.zipcode = stoi(zipcodeText);
    }
}
void displayEmployee(ostream& out, const Employee& e){

  //you can access the specific name values this way:
  cout <<  e.name.first << " " << e.name.last << endl;

  return;
}
```